# How to mute the microphone & hang-up the phone programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, mute

I am trying to build a button into my app that mutes the phone microphone during phone call and another button that hangs-up the phone.  I essentially want to emulate the functionality of the phone "mute" and "hang-up" buttons from within my app.

Comment: You can't do this.   Your app can't control other apps due to sandboxing

Comment: Paulw11 - Thanks for pointing me to read-up on "sandboxing".  It makes a lot of sense, but I will have to rethink my app.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction. Rdcmole.